# Break a for loop AND also throw an exception when a specific condition is happening

Tags: for-loop, exception, java-8, break, throw

So I'm looping over a list of accounts and I wanna break the whole "for loop" for all the accounts in the list, and also at the same time to throw an exception as a certain condition is happening:

```
 accounts.forEach(account -> {
     try {
         if (isSomethingHappens()) {
             String errorMsg = "bla bla, you can't do that cuz condition is happening";
             printError(errorMsg);
             throw new Exception(errorMsg); // AND I also, in addition to the exception, I wanna break the whole loop here
         }
         doA();
         doB();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         printError(e);
     }
}
```

Does somebody have any elegant way to do that?
Maybe wrapping it with an exception of my own and on this certain case to catch only it?
Is there a good and known practice for my demand?
I appreciate any help, and tnx a lot!

Comment: use a plain loop.

Comment: Agree with Eugene; when you can't even describe your application logic/problem without using the word "loop", you should use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is - in `forEach` you don't have `break` functionality like traditional `for loop`. so if you need to break for loop use traditional  `for loop`
**In  Java lambda expression can only throw run-time exception** 
so one thing you can do this is create `CustomeRuntimeException` and wrap forEach loop in `try catch` block

```
 try {
    accounts.forEach(account -> {
       if (isSomethingHappens()) {
           throw new CustomeRuntimeException("bla bla, you can't do that cuz condition is happening");
        }
     }
 } catch (CustomeRuntimeException e) {
    printError(e);
 }
    doA();
    doB();
}
```

by dooing this if `isSomethingHappens` return ture than `CustomeRuntimeException` will throw and it will catched by `catch` block and `doA()` & `doB()` method will execute after catch

Answer (score 0):

One good way to do this is to *re-raise* the error in your inner `catch` block.  This will hand control to the next-outer try/catch.  So, put another try/catch block outside of your `foreach` construct.

- The exception occurs and is caught by the innermost `try`.
- The `printError()` stuff is done.
- The exception is re-raised, which kills the `forEach`.
- The `try` that surrounds the `forEach` catches the re-raised exception.